# .NET SslStream doesn't close TLS connection properly

Tags: .net, ssl, sslstream

.NET's `SslStream` class does not send the `close_notify` alert before closing the connection.

How can I send the `close_notify` alert manually?

Comment: perhaps post some cut-down code?

Comment: No need for the code, simply saying SslStream.Close() method works incorrectly.

The other side expects close_notify alert to be send, SslStream doesn't do that.

Comment: FYI, I have posted a bug request to Microsoft at https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/788752/sslstream-does-not-properly-send-the-close-notify-alert

Answer (score 23):

Thanks for this question. It pointed me into the right direction, that there is a bug in .Net, which I do not very often think about.

I bumped into this problem during writing of my implementation of FTPS server and Filezilla (or GnuTLS probably) client was complaining "GnuTLS error -110 in gnutls_record_recv: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated". I think it is a quite significant drawback in SslStream implementation.

So I ended up with writing a wrapper which sends this alert before closing the stream:

```
public class FixedSslStream : SslStream {
    public FixedSslStream(Stream innerStream)
        : base(innerStream) {
    }
    public FixedSslStream(Stream innerStream, bool leaveInnerStreamOpen)
        : base(innerStream, leaveInnerStreamOpen) {
    }
    public FixedSslStream(Stream innerStream, bool leaveInnerStreamOpen, RemoteCertificateValidationCallback userCertificateValidationCallback)
        : base(innerStream, leaveInnerStreamOpen, userCertificateValidationCallback) {
    }
    public FixedSslStream(Stream innerStream, bool leaveInnerStreamOpen, RemoteCertificateValidationCallback userCertificateValidationCallback, LocalCertificateSelectionCallback userCertificateSelectionCallback)
        : base(innerStream, leaveInnerStreamOpen, userCertificateValidationCallback, userCertificateSelectionCallback) {
    }
    public FixedSslStream(Stream innerStream, bool leaveInnerStreamOpen, RemoteCertificateValidationCallback userCertificateValidationCallback, LocalCertificateSelectionCallback userCertificateSelectionCallback, EncryptionPolicy encryptionPolicy)
        : base(innerStream, leaveInnerStreamOpen, userCertificateValidationCallback, userCertificateSelectionCallback, encryptionPolicy) {
    }
    public override void Close() {
        try {
            SslDirectCall.CloseNotify(this);
        } finally {
            base.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

And the following code is to make it working (this code requires assembly to be 'unsafe'):

```
public unsafe static class SslDirectCall {
    public static void CloseNotify(SslStream sslStream) {
        if (sslStream.IsAuthenticated) {
            bool isServer = sslStream.IsServer;

            byte[] result;
            int resultSz;
            var asmbSystem = typeof(System.Net.Authorization).Assembly;

            int SCHANNEL_SHUTDOWN = 1;
            var workArray = BitConverter.GetBytes(SCHANNEL_SHUTDOWN);

            var sslstate = ReflectUtil.GetField(sslStream, "_SslState");
            var context = ReflectUtil.GetProperty(sslstate, "Context");

            var securityContext = ReflectUtil.GetField(context, "m_SecurityContext");
            var securityContextHandleOriginal = ReflectUtil.GetField(securityContext, "_handle");
            NativeApi.SSPIHandle securityContextHandle = default(NativeApi.SSPIHandle);
            securityContextHandle.HandleHi = (IntPtr)ReflectUtil.GetField(securityContextHandleOriginal, "HandleHi");
            securityContextHandle.HandleLo = (IntPtr)ReflectUtil.GetField(securityContextHandleOriginal, "HandleLo");

            var credentialsHandle = ReflectUtil.GetField(context, "m_CredentialsHandle");
            var credentialsHandleHandleOriginal = ReflectUtil.GetField(credentialsHandle, "_handle");
            NativeApi.SSPIHandle credentialsHandleHandle = default(NativeApi.SSPIHandle);
            credentialsHandleHandle.HandleHi = (IntPtr)ReflectUtil.GetField(credentialsHandleHandleOriginal, "HandleHi");
            credentialsHandleHandle.HandleLo = (IntPtr)ReflectUtil.GetField(credentialsHandleHandleOriginal, "HandleLo");

            int bufferSize = 1;
            NativeApi.SecurityBufferDescriptor securityBufferDescriptor = new NativeApi.SecurityBufferDescriptor(bufferSize);
            NativeApi.SecurityBufferStruct[] unmanagedBuffer = new NativeApi.SecurityBufferStruct[bufferSize];

            fixed (NativeApi.SecurityBufferStruct* ptr = unmanagedBuffer)
            fixed (void* workArrayPtr = workArray) {
                securityBufferDescriptor.UnmanagedPointer = (void*)ptr;

                unmanagedBuffer[0].token = (IntPtr)workArrayPtr;
                unmanagedBuffer[0].count = workArray.Length;
                unmanagedBuffer[0].type = NativeApi.BufferType.Token;

                NativeApi.SecurityStatus status;
                status = (NativeApi.SecurityStatus)NativeApi.ApplyControlToken(ref securityContextHandle, securityBufferDescriptor);
                if (status == NativeApi.SecurityStatus.OK) {
                    unmanagedBuffer[0].token = IntPtr.Zero;
                    unmanagedBuffer[0].count = 0;
                    unmanagedBuffer[0].type = NativeApi.BufferType.Token;

                    NativeApi.SSPIHandle contextHandleOut = default(NativeApi.SSPIHandle);
                    NativeApi.ContextFlags outflags = NativeApi.ContextFlags.Zero;
                    long ts = 0;

                    var inflags = NativeApi.ContextFlags.SequenceDetect |
                                NativeApi.ContextFlags.ReplayDetect |
                                NativeApi.ContextFlags.Confidentiality |
                                NativeApi.ContextFlags.AcceptExtendedError |
                                NativeApi.ContextFlags.AllocateMemory |
                                NativeApi.ContextFlags.InitStream;

                    if (isServer) {
                        status = (NativeApi.SecurityStatus)NativeApi.AcceptSecurityContext(ref credentialsHandleHandle, ref securityContextHandle, null,
                            inflags, NativeApi.Endianness.Native, ref contextHandleOut, securityBufferDescriptor, ref outflags, out ts);
                    } else {
                        status = (NativeApi.SecurityStatus)NativeApi.InitializeSecurityContextW(ref credentialsHandleHandle, ref securityContextHandle, null,
                            inflags, 0, NativeApi.Endianness.Native, null, 0, ref contextHandleOut, securityBufferDescriptor, ref outflags, out ts);
                    }
                    if (status == NativeApi.SecurityStatus.OK) {
                        byte[] resultArr = new byte[unmanagedBuffer[0].count];
                        Marshal.Copy(unmanagedBuffer[0].token, resultArr, 0, resultArr.Length);
                        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(unmanagedBuffer[0].token);
                        result = resultArr;
                        resultSz = resultArr.Length;
                    } else {
                        throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("AcceptSecurityContext/InitializeSecurityContextW returned [{0}] during CloseNotify.", status));
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("ApplyControlToken returned [{0}] during CloseNotify.", status));
                }
            }

            var innerStream = (Stream)ReflectUtil.GetProperty(sslstate, "InnerStream");
            innerStream.Write(result, 0, resultSz);
        }
    }
}
```

Windows API used:

```
public unsafe static class NativeApi {
    internal enum BufferType {
        Empty,
        Data,
        Token,
        Parameters,
        Missing,
        Extra,
        Trailer,
        Header,
        Padding = 9,
        Stream,
        ChannelBindings = 14,
        TargetHost = 16,
        ReadOnlyFlag = -2147483648,
        ReadOnlyWithChecksum = 268435456
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    internal struct SSPIHandle {
        public IntPtr HandleHi;
        public IntPtr HandleLo;
        public bool IsZero {
            get {
                return this.HandleHi == IntPtr.Zero && this.HandleLo == IntPtr.Zero;
            }
        }
        [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
        internal void SetToInvalid() {
            this.HandleHi = IntPtr.Zero;
            this.HandleLo = IntPtr.Zero;
        }
        public override string ToString() {
            return this.HandleHi.ToString("x") + ":" + this.HandleLo.ToString("x");
        }
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal class SecurityBufferDescriptor {
        public readonly int Version;
        public readonly int Count;
        public unsafe void* UnmanagedPointer;
        public SecurityBufferDescriptor(int count) {
            this.Version = 0;
            this.Count = count;
            this.UnmanagedPointer = null;
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct SecurityBufferStruct {
        public int count;
        public BufferType type;
        public IntPtr token;
        public static readonly int Size = sizeof(SecurityBufferStruct);
    }

    internal enum SecurityStatus {
        OK,
        ContinueNeeded = 590610,
        CompleteNeeded,
        CompAndContinue,
        ContextExpired = 590615,
        CredentialsNeeded = 590624,
        Renegotiate,
        OutOfMemory = -2146893056,
        InvalidHandle,
        Unsupported,
        TargetUnknown,
        InternalError,
        PackageNotFound,
        NotOwner,
        CannotInstall,
        InvalidToken,
        CannotPack,
        QopNotSupported,
        NoImpersonation,
        LogonDenied,
        UnknownCredentials,
        NoCredentials,
        MessageAltered,
        OutOfSequence,
        NoAuthenticatingAuthority,
        IncompleteMessage = -2146893032,
        IncompleteCredentials = -2146893024,
        BufferNotEnough,
        WrongPrincipal,
        TimeSkew = -2146893020,
        UntrustedRoot,
        IllegalMessage,
        CertUnknown,
        CertExpired,
        AlgorithmMismatch = -2146893007,
        SecurityQosFailed,
        SmartcardLogonRequired = -2146892994,
        UnsupportedPreauth = -2146892989,
        BadBinding = -2146892986
    }
    [Flags]
    internal enum ContextFlags {
        Zero = 0,
        Delegate = 1,
        MutualAuth = 2,
        ReplayDetect = 4,
        SequenceDetect = 8,
        Confidentiality = 16,
        UseSessionKey = 32,
        AllocateMemory = 256,
        Connection = 2048,
        InitExtendedError = 16384,
        AcceptExtendedError = 32768,
        InitStream = 32768,
        AcceptStream = 65536,
        InitIntegrity = 65536,
        AcceptIntegrity = 131072,
        InitManualCredValidation = 524288,
        InitUseSuppliedCreds = 128,
        InitIdentify = 131072,
        AcceptIdentify = 524288,
        ProxyBindings = 67108864,
        AllowMissingBindings = 268435456,
        UnverifiedTargetName = 536870912
    }
    internal enum Endianness {
        Network,
        Native = 16
    }

    [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail)]
    [DllImport("secur32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern int ApplyControlToken(ref SSPIHandle contextHandle, [In] [Out] SecurityBufferDescriptor outputBuffer);

    [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail)]
    [DllImport("secur32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    internal unsafe static extern int AcceptSecurityContext(ref SSPIHandle credentialHandle, ref SSPIHandle contextHandle, [In] SecurityBufferDescriptor inputBuffer, [In] ContextFlags inFlags, [In] Endianness endianness, ref SSPIHandle outContextPtr, [In] [Out] SecurityBufferDescriptor outputBuffer, [In] [Out] ref ContextFlags attributes, out long timeStamp);

    [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail)]
    [DllImport("secur32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    internal unsafe static extern int InitializeSecurityContextW(ref SSPIHandle credentialHandle, ref SSPIHandle contextHandle, [In] byte* targetName, [In] ContextFlags inFlags, [In] int reservedI, [In] Endianness endianness, [In] SecurityBufferDescriptor inputBuffer, [In] int reservedII, ref SSPIHandle outContextPtr, [In] [Out] SecurityBufferDescriptor outputBuffer, [In] [Out] ref ContextFlags attributes, out long timeStamp);
}
```

Reflection utilities:

```
public static class ReflectUtil {
    public static object GetField(object obj, string fieldName) {
        var tp = obj.GetType();
        var info = GetAllFields(tp)
            .Where(f => f.Name == fieldName).Single();
        return info.GetValue(obj);
    }
    public static void SetField(object obj, string fieldName, object value) {
        var tp = obj.GetType();
        var info = GetAllFields(tp)
            .Where(f => f.Name == fieldName).Single();
        info.SetValue(obj, value);
    }
    public static object GetStaticField(Assembly assembly, string typeName, string fieldName) {
        var tp = assembly.GetType(typeName);
        var info = GetAllFields(tp)
            .Where(f => f.IsStatic)
            .Where(f => f.Name == fieldName).Single();
        return info.GetValue(null);
    }

    public static object GetProperty(object obj, string propertyName) {
        var tp = obj.GetType();
        var info = GetAllProperties(tp)
            .Where(f => f.Name == propertyName).Single();
        return info.GetValue(obj, null);
    }
    public static object CallMethod(object obj, string methodName, params object[] prm) {
        var tp = obj.GetType();
        var info = GetAllMethods(tp)
            .Where(f => f.Name == methodName && f.GetParameters().Length == prm.Length).Single();
        object rez = info.Invoke(obj, prm);
        return rez;
    }
    public static object NewInstance(Assembly assembly, string typeName, params object[] prm) {
        var tp = assembly.GetType(typeName);
        var info = tp.GetConstructors()
            .Where(f => f.GetParameters().Length == prm.Length).Single();
        object rez = info.Invoke(prm);
        return rez;
    }
    public static object InvokeStaticMethod(Assembly assembly, string typeName, string methodName, params object[] prm) {
        var tp = assembly.GetType(typeName);
        var info = GetAllMethods(tp)
            .Where(f => f.IsStatic)
            .Where(f => f.Name == methodName && f.GetParameters().Length == prm.Length).Single();
        object rez = info.Invoke(null, prm);
        return rez;
    }
    public static object GetEnumValue(Assembly assembly, string typeName, int value) {
        var tp = assembly.GetType(typeName);
        object rez = Enum.ToObject(tp, value);
        return rez;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<FieldInfo> GetAllFields(Type t) {
        if (t == null)
            return Enumerable.Empty<FieldInfo>();

        BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                             BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance |
                             BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly;
        return t.GetFields(flags).Concat(GetAllFields(t.BaseType));
    }
    private static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetAllProperties(Type t) {
        if (t == null)
            return Enumerable.Empty<PropertyInfo>();

        BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                             BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance |
                             BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly;
        return t.GetProperties(flags).Concat(GetAllProperties(t.BaseType));
    }
    private static IEnumerable<MethodInfo> GetAllMethods(Type t) {
        if (t == null)
            return Enumerable.Empty<MethodInfo>();

        BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                             BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance |
                             BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly;
        return t.GetMethods(flags).Concat(GetAllMethods(t.BaseType));
    }
}
```

I am not experienced in writing reliable interaction with unmanaged environment, so I hope somebody can have a look and fix issues (and maybe make it 'safe').

Comment: Interesting, I will take a look at this.

Comment: This seems to work well, thanks! Wish MS would just create an SslStream2 or something.

Comment: I would love to know how you actually managed to work all this out and how long it took

Comment: If I am not mistaken it took ~3 weeks (evenings and weekends). I was moving in several ways in parallel - researching MS assemblies (to see how it works), researching an open source project (to see how it should work - I do not remember exactly where I took the algorthm from; I believe it was GnuTLS or Filezilla) and researching Internet to get a general understanding.

Comment: Well I for one tip my hat, that's not some every day code, thanks for sharing

Comment: Thank you for your kind words, Storm! It is really nice to hear that my code helps others.

Comment: @Neco I set up a Github repo for your code at https://github.com/nerai/FixedSslLib and set up LGPL as license with the goal to make it more easily accessible. Please let me know if that's fine with you or if you would prefer any changes.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in .NET's usage of the underlying security API. Note another question by me about being unable to select a specific cypher suite - they really botched up this API wrapper...

Answer (score 1):

For the record, SslStream at least in .NET 2.0 also doesn't appear to response to a close_notify from the other side.  This means that calling OpenSSL's SSL_Shutdown() properly, i.e. twice - once to initiate the shutdown and again to wait for the response - will hang on the second call.