# FTPS Server using .NET SslStream

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, ftps

I'm developing a FTP server in C#, I just finished implementing FTPS explicit mode functionality using `SslStream` class and everything goes almost ok.

I'm having problems using fileZilla > 3.0.11 as client. I google arround, and it seems that `sslstream` implementation does not close the connection properly. (not sending `close_notify` alert). Using WinScp, SmartFTP and lftp everithing works fine.

Any ideas or any other SSL library?

Or maybe some way to hardcode the `close_notify` alert and send it?

Concrete code example would be great!

Creating sslStream:

```
_sslStream = new SslStream(socket.GetStream());      
var _cert = new X509Certificate2(certPath,pass);    
_sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(_cert);
```

Closing connections:

```
_sslStream.Close();
socket.Close();
_sslStream = null;
socket = null;
```

FileZilla 3.6.0.2 Error log:

```
Response:   150 Opening data connection for LIST
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::TransferParseResponse()
Trace:    code = 1
Trace:    state = 4
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::TransferSend()
Trace:    state = 5
Trace:  CTlsSocket::OnRead()
Trace:  CTlsSocket::ContinueHandshake()
Trace:  TLS Handshake successful
Trace:  TLS Session resumed
Trace:  Cipher: AES-128-CBC, MAC: SHA1
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnConnect
Trace:  CTransferSocket::OnReceive(), m_transferMode=0
Trace:  CTlsSocket::Failure(-110, 0)
Error:  GnuTLS error -110 in gnutls_record_recv: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
Error:  Could not read from transfer socket: ECONNABORTED - Connection aborted
Trace:  CTransferSocket::TransferEnd(3)
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::TransferEnd()
Trace:  CTlsSocket::OnRead()
Trace:  CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
Response:   226 LIST successful.
```

Comment: How are you closing the steam? Please show your code.

Comment: I just recalled - I had same problem with Filezilla when was implementing our FTPS server. Solved it by fixing SSL classes, however you have no this choise using SSL stream. So you can 1) ignore Filezilla 2) Submit a patch to GnuTLS which will ignore this error :) 3) Open a case somewhere on Microsoft forums - this behavior is not standard-compliant, since RFC clearly requires "Each party is required to send a close_notify alert before closing the write side of the connection."

Comment: Same problem here, did you ever found a working solution?

Answer (score 5):

I think, you have a real reason to re-invent the wheel. Already there are libraries which implements FTPS server in C#/.NET, like [SecureBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/desc-ftps.php) (however, it is commercial).

Comment: Thanks!. Anyway, do you know any free library?

Comment: For FTPS server - unfortunately, no. But for SSL/TLS stuff there is BouncyCastle library - free and open-source.

Comment: @Morvader SecureBlackbox offers both SSL/TLS layer (much more flexible and powerful than BouncyCastle) and two FTPS server components (low-level component and high-level one).

Comment: Any code example about secure FTP connections using BouncyCastle?. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, don't have examples. However you can download SecureBlackbox and got a working FTPS server demo from-the-box.

Answer (score 3):

Please have a look at a workaround I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237807/net-sslstream-doesnt-close-tsl-connection-properly/22626756#22626756). It would be great if all together we could make this workaround better.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you call Shutdown on the Socket before closing it?

```
socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
_sslStream.Dispose();
```

I'm wondering if the Dispose method handles the `close_notify`.

Comment: Not solving the problem :( .Thanks!